# Opening AngularJS Accordion on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, accordion, angular-directive

Hi I am working with an angular controller and an angular view.

In my view I have the following:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
   <input type="search" class="form-control" ng-model="Filter" placeholder="Filter Search" />
    <accordion>
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.title}}">
        {{group.content}}
        </accordion-group>    
    </accordion>
</div>
```

And then in my controller I want to be able to do two things:

1. Open the accordion completely using 'is-open' on every group
2. Somewhat related set "close-others=false"

I know how to set that two things as defaults, but my problem is that I need to do this from my controller since I basically am using an ng-model to look at changes in a search box and the moment the user start typing into this search box I want the accordion to open up completely...and eventually I'm going to user ._filter to actually do the filtering..but the first step is to trigger an open up of the accordion

Right now my controller looks like this

```
$scope.$watch("Filter", function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        console.log($scope.reportFilter);

        if ($scope.Filter)
        {
            if ($scope.Filter.length == 0){
                // close the accordion
                // show one at a time

            }

            else{

                // open the entire accordion

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the html:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
   <input type="search" class="form-control" ng-model="Filter" placeholder="Filter Search" />
    <accordion close-others="showOnlyOne">
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.title}}" is-open="group.isThisOpen">
        {{group.content}}
        </accordion-group>    
    </accordion>
</div>
```

And for the Controller:

```
$scope.showOnlyOne=true;
$scope.$watch("Filter", function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        console.log($scope.reportFilter);

        if ($scope.Filter)
        {
            if ($scope.Filter.length == 0){
                // close the accordion
                // show one at a time
                $scope.showOnlyOne=true;
                $scope.groups.forEach(function(group){
                    group.isThisOpen=false;
                });
            }

            else{
                $scope.showOnlyOne=false;
                // open the entire accordion
                $scope.groups.forEach(function(group){
                    group.isThisOpen=true;
                });
            }
        }
};
```

Probably that'll do the trick...